# Looking for the complete SharedAllocator source presented in Dr. Dobb's 2003/04/01 article

Tags: allocator

I need to share STL::map between multiple processes without using Boost library (I just don't like using it).  Then internet search led me to:

> http://www.drdobbs.com/creating-stl-containers-in-shared-memory/184401639?pgno=1
>
> **Creating STL Containers in Shared Memory By Grum Ketema, April 01, 2003**
>
> The complete source code is available for download at
>   http://www.cuj.com/code.

I was so happy to hurry to download the complete source but unfortunately, not there any more.

If anyone has this source code, please share it with me.
I really need it.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) clearly says this sort of question is off-topic here. Your experiences at this site will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages in order to learn how this site works and what is (and is not) appropriate to ask here before you begin posting.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the complete source and it can be downloaded from:
https://collaboration.cmc.ec.gc.ca/science/rpn/biblio/ddj/Website/source/CUJ/2003/apr03.zip

But unfortunately, it is not for Windows but Linux/Unix.

I hope someone can covert it to Windows version.